# Create a homescreen widget gui programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm creating a weatherapp to which I am also creating a homescreen widget. the widget will show the weather for a number of locations based on the user settings of the app. Because the user can choose to show any number of locations I don't think that I can use the xml layouts and instead I'm thinking that I should create the gui programmatically but how!

I can't find any way to set the gui (like setContentView on activity) or get a hold off the gui from the xml (I have an xml with an empty linearlayout that I thought that I could add views to)

How to create the widget gui programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by myself.. after a lot of trial and error. I thought that I post my solution here.

I created an xml.file that I call entity.xml that contains the views that I need to represent one location. I also create another xml-file called widgetLayout.xml that contains an empty linearLayout.

Then I do this when I want to dynamicly create the widgets layout.

```
      RemoteViews main = new     RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),      R.layout.widget_layout);
    main.removeAllViews(R.id.main);


    RemoteViews location = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.entity);
    location.setTextViewText(R.id.SpotName, "loc");

    RemoteViews location2 = new      RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.entity);
    spot1.setTextViewText(R.id.SpotName, "loc2");

    main.addView(R.id.main, location);
    main.addView(R.id.main, location2);

    int[] allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds[0], main);
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that your solution will be accessible to others with the same problem.  Cheers~